# Adobe XD exporting SVG with missing vector objects

Tags: vector, svg, adobe-xd

I am trying to export a vector as svg from Adobe Xd, the problem is that some of its objects are missing.

The vector consists of:

1. One circle created using the ellipse tool.
2. One triangle created using the polygon tool.
3. One half-circle created by subtracting a rectangle from a circle.

Items 2 and 3 are missing in the exported SVG, and I am not sure why. I am exporting with the format of SVG, styling set to "Presentation Attributes", and save images with only "Embed" selected.

I have tried using both export only selected and export all artboards.

Answer (score -1):

Select objects in a group or across multiple groups

Normally, you can select an object by simply clicking it. When the object is part of a group, the whole group is selected when you click the object.

To select an object in a group, double-click or Cmd + click / Ctrl + Click the object in the group.

To select objects across multiple groups, use Cmd/Ctrl+Shift+Click to add objects to the selection independent of which groups they're part of. Once selected, you can easily change common attributes in the Properties Inspector and group, lock, toggle visibility and so on.

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevant portions into your answer,

Comment: @Mayo I did the change